# Determining which control raised the postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Any ideas how to check which control in an asp.net web application raised a postback?

I have a number of buttons, and want to perform a different task in the Page_Load method depending which button was clicked.

Comment: Why not do them in their appropriate click event handlers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check which control caused the postback, use Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]. This should return a unique ID of the control that caused the postback.

**EDIT**
For this to work you will have to set `UseSubmitBehavior` property of the button to false which causes it to use Asp Net post back mechanism

> Use the UseSubmitBehavior property to specify whether a Button control uses the client browser's submit mechanism or the ASP.NET postback mechanism. By default the value of this property is true, causing the Button control to use the browser's submit mechanism. If you specify false, the ASP.NET page framework adds client-side script to the page to post the form to the server.
>
> When the UseSubmitBehavior property is false, control developers can use the GetPostBackEventReference method to return the client postback event for the Button. The string returned by the GetPostBackEventReference method contains the text of the client-side function call and can be inserted into a client-side event handler.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is applicable for a button click

Comment: @shaun.breach well not unless you set `UseSubmitBehavior` to false, check out the same in the link by Henk

Comment: @V4Vendetta Seems you are correct, it works for postbacks caused by text boxes, but not buttons. Any idea why?

Comment: @53AN I have edited the answer for additional info, you are free to retain it or revert back to the original one

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks for clarifying my answer, I have only just checked back since my original post. I did know about the SubmitBehavior however I didn't include it. In future I will try to expand on my answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Postback control id from the '__EVENTTARGET' value in the requist. params

Have a look at the following [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx).

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the method handler of the button the event it contains a reference to the button so you can get to the controls id:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender).ID
}
```

the EventArgs parameter contains the command name which can be used to identify what you need to do:

```
if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
{   
    Do something
}
```